# onclick Javascript void does not open a new tab

Tags: javascript, html

On right clicking the hyperlink,`Open link in new tab` options is not disabled for javascript hyperlink in chrome. when we click the `open in new tab` options, Chrome browser opens the "About blank" page.

On the other hand, Mozilla firefox & IE disables ,`Open link in new tab` options.

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
        <script>
            function myJsFunc() {
                alert("myJsFunc");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a JavaScript URL is to generate a document, for display, from JavaScript.

Linking to a JavaScript URL that generates an explicit "nothing" doesn't make sense.

If you want an element that just fires an onclick event: Use a button. Don't use a link and then try to neuter the primary function of a link.

```js
function myJsFunc() {
  alert("myJsFunc");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", myJsFunc);
```

```html
<button>Run JavaScript Code</button>
```